# Check tag existence in python xml.etree.ElementTree module

Tags: python

There is a function of the xml.etree.ElementTree module to do that?
NOT:

```
if node.find(tag)!=None:
    #code
    pass
```

Comment: what wrong in `find()` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's exactly what you've presented. [`find()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.Element.find) is the tool for the job:

> Finds the first subelement matching match. match may be a tag name or path. **Returns an element instance or `None`**.

It's just that, to follow the best practices, use `is` when comparing to `None`:

```
if node.find(tag) is not None:
    # code
```